# Add Padding to video

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I have a video which size is 576 x 1024, my screen phone is 576 x 2044. I want to make the height of video is 2044 (full screen) and add padding black background both top and bottom. What can I do ? I currently use **FFmpeg library**.

I want to process video in android **kotlin**, and I use some commands but it it doesn't work.

Example:

```
fun makeVideoFullScreen(
    context: Context,
    inputVideoPath: String,
    screenWidth: Int,
    screenHeight: Int,
    listener : (outputPath: String, returnCode: Int) -> Unit
){
    val fileName = Utility.getCurrentTime()
    val externalDir = context.getExternalFilesDir(null)
    val file = File(externalDir, "temp_video${fileName}.mp4")
    val outputPath = file.absolutePath

    val cmd = arrayOf(
        "-i", inputVideoPath,
        "-vf", "scale=-1:$screenHeight, pad=$screenWidth:$screenHeight:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2:black",
        "-c:v", "libx264",
        "-preset", "ultrafast",
        "-c:a", "copy",
        outputPath
    )

    FFmpeg.executeAsync(cmd
    ) { _, returnCode ->
        listener(outputPath, returnCode)
    }
}
```